# Show that $|\int_{C} \frac{1}{z^{3}+1}\, dz|\leq \frac{\pi}{3}(\frac{R}{R^{3}-1})$

Tags: real-analysis

Could someone help me through this problem?

Let C be an arc of the circle $|z|=R$, with $R>1$ of angle $\frac{\pi}{3}$.

Show that $\left|\displaystyle\int_{C} \frac{1}{z^{3}+1}\, dz\right|\leq \dfrac{\pi}{3}\left(\dfrac{R}{R^{3}-1}\right)$

and deduce $\lim\limits_{R \to{+}\infty}{\displaystyle\int_{C} \frac{1}{z^{3}+1}\, dz}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For any contour $\Gamma$ one has that

$$\left|\int_\Gamma f(z)\;dz\right|\leqslant \|f\|_\infty|\Gamma|$$

Where $|\Gamma|$ is the arc-length of $\gamma$.

Comment: As a supplement to this hint, for any complex $a$ and $b$ one has $|a - b| \geq ||a| - |b||$.  So in particular, if $|z| = R > 1$, putting $a = z^3$ and $b = -1$ one deduces that $|z^3 + 1| \geq R^3 - 1$.